# Can I use phonegap to build the same app for iOS and Android?

Tags: cordova

I'm planning to make a tablet application using phonegap. In my presentation I want to keep five buttons.

- First button is  to load html page in phonegap application.
- Second button is  to load flash or unity3d app/apk in application.
- Third button  to load video
- Fourth button  to show video (half page) and half page for html page means at the same time I want to show html document and video on same page with the use of webview and videoview.
- Fifth button is  to load xml or sqlite generated quiz (multiple choice question)

So is it possible to load external applications using phonegap for both iOS and android? If is it possible than please tell me how to do it.

I want to make one application for iOS and android.

Answer (score 4):

for using phonegap between IOS and android:

- yes you can, but you must code the app to expand dynamically with the screen size due to the variation of screen sizes on android. This can be achieved with a fluid css layout.

for the second button on your app:

- flash cannot be used on iphone and you cannot open an .app inside an iphone app.
- as for android you can definitely open flash but i'm not sure you can launch an .apk

Comment: You can't. `.apk` files are meant to be _installed_ (once), not _run_ (many times). Android is running executable files, extracted from `.apk` files, during installation process. It does not run `.apk` files directly. You can test it, by going to `PhoneGap Build` site with your mobile device. Once you tap on `.apk` file in Android section of your newly built application, you'll be only allowed to download this file, not to run it directly from a website.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that is one of the major advantages of phonegap build. One zip file with your html/javascript/css code supports ios, android, blackberry, windows phone, and more. You do need to have an apple developer program account in order to build the ios app. This is a great tool that I have used multiple times.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is the only purpose of PhoneGap. You need to first follow the steps to create the PhoneGap project for both the iOS and Android. For this, you can use the link :-

```
http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.4.0/guide_cli_index.md.html#The%20Command-Line%20Interface
```

Now you can club your HTML/CSS/JS files into the common www folder, which you can use for any mobile platform which supports PhoneGap.