# Convert an Android PhoneGap app to iOS Using Linux and Command Line

Tags: android, ios, linux, cordova

First of all, I want to acknowledge that this question has been answered for Windows users-- apparently it is possible to make an iOS PhoneGap app without using a Mac. I have seen some cautions about trying it, but I don't know how current any of the information is.

Here are some example links saying it is possible:

[Detailed Guide for Setting Up Building iOS Apps Without a Mac](http://community.phonegap.com/nitobi/topics/detailed_guide_for_setting_up_building_ios_apps_without_a_mac)

[Can I use phonegap to build the same app for iOS and Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8692083/can-i-use-phonegap-to-build-the-same-app-for-ios-and-android)

[Convert android app to IOS using phonegap?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20560091/convert-android-app-to-ios-using-phonegap)

I've not been able to find authoritative instructions for Linux users like myself (I'm using Ubuntu, and I'm not a power-user, but pretty knowledgeable).

I've tried to add the iOS library:

```
$ sudo cordova platform add ios
```

I get the following error:

```
Downloading cordova library for ios...
Download complete
Creating ios project...
/home/jasonsilver/.cordova/lib/ios/cordova/3.5.0/bin/create: 33: /home/jasonsilver/.cordova/lib/ios/cordova/3.5.0/bin/create: Syntax error: "(" unexpected
Error: /home/jasonsilver/.cordova/lib/ios/cordova/3.5.0/bin/create: Command failed with exit code 2
at ChildProcess.whenDone (/usr/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/cordova-lib/src/cordova/superspawn.js:135:23)
at ChildProcess.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:98:17)
at maybeClose (child_process.js:743:16)
at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:810:5)
```

When researching this error, I find articles explaining how I cannot develop for iOS on Linux:
https://github.com/driftyco/ionic/issues/1596

[Can't Complete Install Steps in Chapter 2 Getting Everything Installed](http://forum.ionicframework.com/t/can-t-complete-install-steps-in-chapter-2-getting-everything-installed/7066/3)

So it seems to be a run-around.

Can anyone give me a new place to look, or an authoritative answer?

Thanks!

Comment: The reference links given for building on windows are very old. Apple now requires you to build and upload with Xcode or the application loader which are only available on OSX.

Comment: Thanks @rckoenes, that makes sense. I thought the whole point of PhoneGap was to allow cross platform development using the same source code.

Comment: That is true, but you will still need to build the whole project and submit app to Apple.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first article you posted, shows how to create an phonegap app that is to be built via the phonegap build service in the cloud.  This will get you an app compiled for a number of different mobile devices, including ios.  The article implies you can create the app certificate without xcode, but I can't vouch for it being actually possible.  Nonetheless, you are going to have to create a provisioning profile to be able to distribute the ios app; so you'll need to join the IOS developer program.

There seems to be no problem submitting an app created using phonegap build to the Apple app store.

Also, not every cordova plugin is supported by phonegap build, in which case you are out of luck. The supported plugins are listed here: https://build.phonegap.com/plugins.

However, you'll never be able to add the ios platform to a cordova project if you aren't on a mac. In a similar vein, you can't add the android platform, unless you have the android SDK installed.

Comment: Thanks for the clear answer @robert-moskal -- I'm wondering why it's so difficult to find this information?

Comment: I've been working through these issues, myself these last few weeks.

Comment: I will likely accept your answer, I'm just holding out hope that someone else will reply with something more palatable. :-/